# Shortcuts do not appear in dock on login

Tags: gnome, launcher

When I first login to GNOME there are no shortcuts in the dock. If I click on activities and search for an application at this time I can start it. After about 30 seconds they will appear.

Running 21.04

Comment: You're running Wayland, that's (unfortunately) normal.

Comment: thanks for that explanation. do they have any intention to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had an old version of adobe installed which had a bunch of :i386 architecture dependencies. removing that seemed to fix it.